# Reporting service Error when large number of record

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I make reporting service to use in Microsoft Dynamic CRM. Then I have some problem when report run with little number of row report can run success but when report run with a large number of record report can't run (It's show Error)

my Report Have 1 Rows group and 2 Column group like this 
http://upic.me/i/ss/group1.png

And this is my tablix 
http://upic.me/i/j5/group2.png

a number of record (in dataset) that report error is 17180 record 
(1 row in report equals 20 rows in dataset)

but when I use

> SELECT TOP 10000 .....

Report can run

Anyone can help me how to fix this problem I can't reduce rows in dataset

Thank you.

Comment: are you suing stored procedure or T-SQL Query in DataSet...??

Comment: I use T-SQL in DataSet

Comment: ok then use Stored Procedure and check the result. coze  stored procedure is better for large no of records.